A dumb GPS watch
I'm looking for a watch that does GPS and literally nothing else.
I don't want bluetooth.
I don't want a colour touchscreen.
I really really don't want Android or iOS.
I don't want an integrated lemon zester.
I want four numbers:

GPS datetime
Altitude
Latitude
Longitude

The battery life should be as long as possible, ideally the same order of magnitude as a dumb casio or timex.
Why do I want this?
I have my reasons.

Garmin Instinct 2S/2/2X Solar - $399/$399/$449

It's still a little overkill for what you're looking for, but it's pretty damn close, and is a popular model it's from a very reputable manufacturer.

GNSS datetime/positioning with a relatively high refresh rate, with support for GPS, GLONASS, and Galileo
Altimeter, barometer, compass
Monochrome display
Nearly infinite battery life thanks to the solar functionality

Yes, it does have a bunch of other smart-watch-y stuff like notifications, payments, workout tracking, and Bluetooth, but that's all entirely optional. You don't have to pair it to a phone or give it any kind of connection to the internet, so there's no way for Garmin (or anyone else) to Zucc your data if you don't want them to.
While there are many more "traditional" GPS/solar watches, such as the Seiko Astron, they're usually designed as luxury watches first and GPS devices second. As such, they're generally substantially more expensive, and typically only refresh the GPS datetime/position once a day by default (though you usually can trigger a manual update whenever you want). If you're willing to pay for them, they're relatively pretty looking watches, but I wouldn't try to use them as navigational devices generally.

For the record luxury watches usually (95% of the cases) do not show the coordinates, they use GPS to correct/set the time and eventually timezone.
